# Asp.net Core MVC - obtaining dependency during app shutdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm developing a web app using ASP.net Core MVC 2.2, and in my `Startup` class I'm registering a dependency injection of type `MyService`, like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Inject dependency
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>();

    //...other stuff...
}
```

This works correctly. However, I need to retrieve the instance of `MyService` during application shutdown, in order to do some cleanup operations before the app terminates.

So I tried doing this - first I injected `IServiceProvider` in my startup class, so it is available:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

and then, in the Configure method, I configured a hook to the `ApplicationStopping` event, to intercept shutdown and call the `OnShutdown` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    //Register app termination event hook
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);

    //...do stuff...
}
```

finally, in my `OnShutdown` method I try obtaining my dependency and using it:

```
private void OnShutdown()
{
    var myService = ServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
    myService.DoSomething(); //NullReference exception, myService is null!
}
```

However, as you can see from the comment in the code, this doesn't work: the returned dependency is always null. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to make it work by explicitly passing your application services to your shutdown method like so.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    //Register app termination event hook
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => OnShutdown(app.ApplicationServices));

     //...do stuff...
}


private void OnShutdown(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
        var myService = serviceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
         myService.DoSomething();
}
```

Bare in mind that this will work for singleton services - you may have to `CreateScope()` if you want to resolve scoped services.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I don't know if the provider is actually disposed (shouldn't it throw some exception if that's the case?) but capturing it in the lambda like you did solved the problem! Thanks.

Comment: @Master_T My next guess would be you are injecting your `ServiceProvider` in the startup class constructor , at time of injection your Service Provider has not been built yet.

Comment: @cl0ud How did you know to use a lambda expression? 
I was trying .Register(OnShutdown(app.ApplicationServices) and getting errors.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy to be entirely honest - Resharper suggested it.